# add a prefix code displayed in toString method based on object subtype

Tags: java, inheritance

I have written a simple program that has an Animal super type and a Dog and Cat subtypes. The subtypes inherit 3 instance variables, name, weightInKg, and animalId. Each subtype has its own unique boolean, barks and swims.

I have a Farm class that adds Animal object to an ArrayList and a method that displays the toString() methods of each object in the collection. I want to create a pre-fix code to be displayed instead of each objects unique animalId in the toString() method. For example, if it is a Dog subtype "d1" will be displayed for all Dog objects.

Is there a way to do this?

I know that the obvious answer would be to put the code in as the animalId but thats not what I am trying to accomplish. Thanks!`

Animal:

```
public class Animal {

    private String name;
    private double weightInKg;
    private String animalId;

    public Animal() {}

    public Animal(String name, double weightInKg, String animalId) {
        setName(name);
        setWeightInKg(weightInKg);
        setAnimalId(animalId);
    }

    //getters and setter ommitted

    public String getAnimalId() {
        return animalId;
    }

    public void setAnimalId(String animalId) {
        this.animalId = animalId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Animal [name=" + name + ", weightInKg=" + weightInKg + ", animalId=" + animalId + "]";
    }
}
```

Dog:

```
public class Dog extends Animal {

    private boolean barks;

    public Dog() {}

    public Dog(String name, double weightInKg, String animalId, boolean barks) {
        super(name, weightInKg, animalId);
        setBarks(barks);
    }

    public boolean isBarks() {
        return barks;
    }

    public void setBarks(boolean barks) {
        this.barks = barks;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Dog [barks=" + barks + ", toString()=" + super.toString() + "]";
    }
}
```

Cat:

```
public class Cat extends Animal {

    private boolean swims;

    public Cat() {}

    public Cat(String name, double weightInKg, String animalId, boolean swims) {
        super(name, weightInKg, animalId);
        setSwims(swims);
    }

    public boolean isSwims() {
        return swims;
    }

    public void setSwims(boolean swims) {
        this.swims = swims;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Cat [swims=" + swims + ", toString()=" + super.toString() + "]";
    }
}
```

Farm:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Farm {

    private ArrayList < Animal > farm;

    public Farm() {
        farm = new ArrayList < Animal > ();
    }

    public void addToFarm(Animal newAnimal) {
        farm.add(newAnimal);
    }

    public void displayAllAnimals() {
        int counter = 0;
        while (farm.size() > counter) {
            System.out.println(farm.get(counter));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% clear on what you what the output to look like, perhaps an example would help.

However you could convert the Animal class to be abstract and add an abstract "prefix" method which all the subclasses would have to implement.  For example:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    ...
    protected abstract String prefix();

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Animal [prefix=" + prefix() + ", name=" + name + ", weightInKg=" + weightInKg + ", animalId=" + animalId + "]";
    }
}
```

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html